# обновить или вставить sql

Tags: sql, spring, jdbc

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в постгресе всё просто:

```
    INSERT INTO statistic (url_id)
VALUES (2) on conflict (url_id) do update
set count = statistic.count + 1 where statistic.url_id = 2;
```

но в идее не работает этот запрос падает с исключением

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: INSERT INTO ***
  VALUES (***')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ***

Comment: Какое исключение возникает?

Comment: @DrMcSheen `on duplicate key` это из mysql. В постгрес синтаксис несколько отличается.